# How to record 30 sec video automatically ?

Tags: android, video-capture

Here the video automatic record program.but it not working properly. We need automatic 30 sec video record and send it to already set email.

```
    package com.example.videorecord;

    import java.io.File;
    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.util.Date;

    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.hardware.Camera;
    import android.hardware.Camera.Parameters;
    import android.media.MediaRecorder;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Environment;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder;
    import android.view.SurfaceHolder.Callback;
    import android.view.SurfaceView;
    import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements Callback {

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        stopRecording();
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private SurfaceHolder surfaceHolder;
    private SurfaceView surfaceView;
    public MediaRecorder mrec = new MediaRecorder();
    private Camera mCamera;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        surfaceView = (SurfaceView) findViewById(R.id.surfaceView1);
        mCamera = Camera.open();

        surfaceHolder = surfaceView.getHolder();
        surfaceHolder.addCallback(this);
        surfaceHolder.setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        menu.add(0, 0, 0, "Start");
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        if (item.getTitle().equals("Start")) {
            try {

                startRecording();
                item.setTitle("Stop");

            } catch (Exception e) {

                String message = e.getMessage();
                Log.i(null, "Problem " + message);
                mrec.release();
            }

        } else if (item.getTitle().equals("Stop")) {
            mrec.stop();
            mrec.release();
            mrec = null;
            item.setTitle("Start");
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    protected void startRecording() throws IOException {
        if (mCamera == null)
            mCamera = Camera.open();

        String filename;
        String path;

        path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()
                .toString();

        Date date = new Date();
        filename = "/rec" + date.toString().replace(" ", "_").replace(":", "_")
                + ".mp4";

        // create empty file it must use
        File file = new File(path, filename);

        mrec = new MediaRecorder();

        mCamera.lock();
        mCamera.unlock();

        // Please maintain sequence of following code.

        // If you change sequence it will not work.
        mrec.setCamera(mCamera);
        mrec.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.CAMERA);
        mrec.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        mrec.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
        mrec.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.MPEG_4_SP);
        mrec.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        mrec.setPreviewDisplay(surfaceHolder.getSurface());
        mrec.setOutputFile(path + filename);
        mrec.prepare();
        mrec.start();

    }

    protected void stopRecording() {

        if (mrec != null) {
            mrec.stop();
            mrec.release();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera.lock();
        }
    }

    private void releaseMediaRecorder() {

        if (mrec != null) {
            mrec.reset(); // clear recorder configuration
            mrec.release(); // release the recorder object
        }
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.release(); // release the camera for other applications
            mCamera = null;
        }

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int width,
            int height) {

    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {

        if (mCamera != null) {
            Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();
            mCamera.setParameters(params);
            Log.i("Surface", "Created");
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Camera not available!",
                    Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            finish();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mCamera.stopPreview();
        mCamera.release();

    }
}
```

Comment: duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22140395/how-to-automatically-record-30sec-video-and-send-via-email-in-a-single-button-cl/22141697#22141697

Answer (score 0):

You can use [CountDownTimer class](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html).

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) 
{

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) 
     {}

     public void onFinish() 
     {
           // stop Video recording
           // call a method which will send video via email.
     }
}.start();
```

Comment: sir,here the video starts recording but seen a black screen in which the camera didn't respond,so how can i fix this problem?

Comment: @user3367503, have you given camera permission ?

Comment: `Parameters params = mCamera.getParameters();` Here in params, you can set camera size. I believe your code is fine.

Answer (score 0):

you just have to write a method mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(30000) in your startRecording() method and when mediaRecorder.stop() function'll be called the video'll be saved in destinantion folder you have set for mediarecorder.